# How can I make DataMaps display in browser?

Tags: javascript, datamaps

I'm trying to embed a DataMap (datamaps.github.io) in my website with Bootstrap and am trying to use the following code as test code.

from http://plnkr.co/edit/W9SbVTm0ovffh5i7ahid?p=preview:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js">
</script>

<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.3/d3.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/topojson/1.6.9/topojson.min.js">
</script>
<script src="http://datamaps.github.io/scripts/0.4.0/datamaps.world.min.js">
</script>


<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#myTab li:eq(0) a").tab('show');
    });

</script>

<body>
<nav>
    <ul class="nav nav-pills center-pills" role="tablist" id="myTab">
        <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#sectionA">Section A</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#sectionB">Section B</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<div class="container">

    <!--<div id="map"></div>-->
    <section>
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div id="sectionA" class="tab-pane fade">
                <H2>sectionA</H2>
                <!-- the map will appear here -->
                <div id="map"></div>

            </div>
            <div id="sectionB" class="tab-pane fade">
                <H2>sectionB</H2>
                <div id="map2"></div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </section>


    <script>
        $('a[data-toggle="pill"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
            console.log(e);
            if (e.target.href.indexOf('sectionA') > -1) {
                console.log("Should Show Map!!");
            }
        });

        var map = new Datamap({
            element: document.getElementById('map'),
            height: 500, width: 500
        });
        var map = new Datamap({
            element: document.getElementById('map2'), fills: {defaultFill: "fa0af0"},
            height: 500, width: 500
        });
    </script>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

However, this doesn't work and I can get the html code to work offline in a browser, but not on my Github Pages site even with identical code. Online, I just get a blank page. I've seen on other StackOverflow answers that the size of the map must be specified for it to work with Bootstrap, but here it is specified and still doesn't display.

Am I missing some script import? Or what are some other possible issues?

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: **I've hosted on my AWS s3 bucket as a website and it worked:**  http://stackoverflow2017.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/

Comment: Could it be an issue with the compatibility of DataMaps and Github Pages then?

Comment: Can you share the Github link?

Comment: https://github.com/vsfsdatateam/vsfsdatateam.github.io/blob/master/index.html

Comment: Sorry, I mean, the link where your project is hosted.

Comment: Sure! https://vsfsdatateam.github.io/index.html

Comment: Remove this line: `<script src="/datamaps.world.min.js"></script>` and try to change from `http` to `https` the urls of your assests.

Comment: That works! Amazing thank you!

Comment: Can you accept my answer and give an upvote.  That would be nice :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You have some tasks that need to be done:**

- Remove this line: `<script src="/datamaps.world.min.js"></script>`
- Change from `http` to `https` the urls of your assets.

**Hope this helps!**